# `as_datetime()` in lubridate package

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

Why there is a strange behavior in the following expressions (why the dates are different):

```
today("America/New_York")
[1] "2021-02-28"

as_datetime(today("America/New_York"), tz = "America/New_York")
[1] "2021-02-27 19:00:00 EST"
```

Also, the local time in New York is 19:09. Is it rounding this time to get "19:00:00"?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `today`, use `now`

```
as_datetime(now("America/New_York"), tz = "America/New_York")
#[1] "2021-02-28 19:16:36 EST"
```

According to `?now`

> now - the current datetime as a POSIXct object

whereas `today` - returns the `Date` which is truncated

```
str(today())
#Date[1:1], format: "2021-02-28"
```

Comment: I was experimenting the outputs of `today()` and `now()` with `as_datetime()`. I agree that `now("America/New_York")` is a better way to handle this. But is there any reason for passing `today("America/New_York") to `datetime` function to give one day less than the actual date?

Comment: @S.Perera It may be because it is dispatching different methods `methods('as_datetime')`.  There is a specific `POSIXct` method

Comment: Thanks. is it the case that `today("America/New_York")` returns `2021-02-28`, but will not store the time zone, so as a result when we pass this to `datetime` function with `tz = "America/New_York"`, it treats `2021-02-28` in `UTC` and gives `2021-02-27` as the answer with `17:00:00` (because NY is 5 hours behind UTC)?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a consequence of using `today()`, which returns a Date not a DateTime. It appears as if applying `as_datetime` starts with the assumption of UTC and then substracts the time zone difference.

The output of `today()` is type Date:

```
str(today(tzone = "America/New_York"))
 Date[1:1], format: "2021-02-28"
```

Without time zone information, `as_datetime` defaults to UTC. Without time data, it seems to assume that the time is midnight on the given date:

```
as_datetime(today(tzone = "America/New_York"))
[1] "2021-02-28 UTC"

str(as_datetime(today(tzone = "America/New_York")))
 POSIXct[1:1], format: "2021-02-28"
```

So when we add time zone information it subtracts 5 hours from midnight, giving 19:00 on the previous date:

```
as_datetime(today(tzone = "America/New_York"), tz = "America/New_York")
[1] "2021-02-27 19:00:00 EST"
```

Note the different methods in `as_datetime`:

```
showMethods("as_datetime")
Function: as_datetime (package lubridate)
x="ANY"
x="character"
x="Date"
    (inherited from: x="ANY")
x="numeric"
x="POSIXt"
```